# Oracle SQL - Display Data from Table A Column 2 to Table B Column 2 and Column 4

Tags: sql, oracle

In the table `Activity Tracking`, there are two columns, `From Location ID` and `To Location ID`. These ID columns match `Location ID` in the `Locations` table, which also contains a `Display Name`, an understandable visual (to tell the user where something is) rather than a jumble of random numbers.

I'm trying to make columns for `From Location Display` and `To Location Display` that pairs with the columns `From Location ID` and `To Location ID` on the same table as `Activity Tracking`, but I cannot figure out how to display the unique values from each column in their related columns.

```sql
select activity_tracking.from_locn as "From Location ID",
       case
       when activity_tracking.from_locn is not null then locations.display_name
       else ''
       end as "From Location",
       activity_tracking.to_locn as "To Location ID",
       case
       when activity_tracking.to_locn is not null then locations.display_name
       else ''
       end as "To Location"
from   activity_tracking
       full join locations
       on activity_tracking.to_locn = locations.location_id
```

I have attached a screen grab of the issue [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWrly.png).

Comment: Please do not post images of data. [Edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data (as text we can copy/paste and execute, not images); and the expected and actual output as text (formatted as a table using markdown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you should join your locations table to your activities table twice - 1. on Location From ID and 2. on Location To ID. Use Left Joins so you could keep all activities rows fetched and have a gap where location id (from or/and to) is misssing....

```sql
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
WITH
    locations (LOCN_ID, DISPL_NAME) AS
        ( Select '001', 'ARK-001-001-A01' From Dual Union All
          Select '008', 'ARK-001-001-A08' From Dual Union All
          Select '009', 'ARK-001-001-B01' From Dual Union All
          Select '052', 'ARK-001-001-F4' From Dual 
        ),
    activities (ID, LOCN_FROM_ID, LOCN_TO_ID) AS
        ( Select 1, '001', '009' From Dual Union All
          Select 2, Null,  '052' From Dual Union All
          Select 3,'008', '052' From Dual Union All
          Select 4, '009', '052' From Dual
        )
```

```sql
--      S Q L :
Select a.LOCN_FROM_ID "FROM_LOCN_ID", lfrom.DISPL_NAME "FROM_LOCN_DISPL",
       a.LOCN_TO_ID "TO_LOCN_ID", lto.DISPL_NAME "TO_LOCN_DISPL"
From   activities a
Left Join locations lfrom ON(a.LOCN_FROM_ID = lfrom.LOCN_ID)
Left Join locations lto ON(a.LOCN_TO_ID = lto.LOCN_ID)
Order By  a.ID
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
FROM_LOCN_ID FROM_LOCN_DISPL TO_LOCN_ID TO_LOCN_DISPL  
------------ --------------- ---------- ---------------
001          ARK-001-001-A01 009        ARK-001-001-B01
                             052        ARK-001-001-F4 
008          ARK-001-001-A08 052        ARK-001-001-F4 
009          ARK-001-001-B01 052        ARK-001-001-F4    */
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much. I actually thought about "renaming" the tables to produce different sets of data for each column, I just never about how to do so. I learned two things from your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have only joined to the locations table once on the `to_locn` column so when you display the display name then the name for the `to_locn` gets displayed for both the `to` and `from` values. Instead you need to either: join twice, once for `from_locn` and once for `to_locn`; or use two correlated sub-queries:

```sql
SELECT a.from_locn as "From Location ID",
       (SELECT display_name FROM locations l WHERE l.location_id = a.from_locn)
         AS "From Location",
       a.to_locn as "To Location ID",
       (SELECT display_name FROM locations l WHERE l.location_id = a.to_locn)
         AS "To Location"
FROM   activity_tracking a
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE locations (location_id, display_name) AS
  SELECT '001', 'ARK-001-001-A01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '008', 'ARK-001-001-A08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '009', 'ARK-001-001-B01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '052', 'ARK-001-001-F04'  FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE activity_tracking (from_locn, to_locn) AS
  SELECT '001', '009' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT Null,  '052' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '008', '052' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '009', '052' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| From Location ID | From Location | To Location ID | To Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | ARK-001-001-A01 | 009 | ARK-001-001-B01 |
| *null* | *null* | 052 | ARK-001-001-F04 |
| 008 | ARK-001-001-A08 | 052 | ARK-001-001-F04 |
| 009 | ARK-001-001-B01 | 052 | ARK-001-001-F04 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/grkE0G_p)